# Do I go to Command Prompt to use: sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser

Tags: command-line, chromium

Somehow Chromium Web Browser is on my computer but it seems like a virus and I can not uninstall it! SO i found the following: To remove an application and all of its configuration files you'll need to purge it. Open up a terminal and run the following command: sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser Do I open Command Prompt and add this:  sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser I am not a computer tech but I'm pretty good at following instructions! Please help me if you can. Thanks, electrikn <><

Comment: Yes, you do this in a terminal window.  It may not remove all of the local configuration files, however.  Those files, like browsing history should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you mean by - it seems like a virus. However here are the steps to remove (purge) it.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Alternatively, you can go to the dashboard and type terminal and select the same)
2. The above step would open a terminal (since you mention command prompt - I believe you are a windows user & yes the terminal would look like a command prompt in windows).
3. In the terminal type `sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser` and hit Enter. It would prompt for your password and remove the chromium browser.